# How to get <li> to display inline when containing React Bootstrap Rows and Columns

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have content that I want to format and display in a horizontal list. It will display horizontally when I have only html in the list, but it won't when I include React Bootstrap grid layout components like Row and Column.

For example, see code below, or see both working and not working reproduced here: [Problem reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-swsbhf?file=src/App.js)

```
//style:
ul#event-list li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>
      <ul id='event-list'>
        <li>Title this</li>
        <li>Title that</li>
        <li>Title the other</li>
        <li>Title again</li>
        <li>Title this</li>
      </ul>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

However, when I try to use Bootstrap grid components inside the `<li>` element, it displays the list vertically. For example, this doesn't work (i.e. displays the list vertically):

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>
      <ul id='event-list'>
        <li>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              Some content
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              Some more content
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

My question is, how do I use React Bootstrap layout options within an `<li>` element while still having it display horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try changing inline to inline-block - hoepfully that would work.